# Is It possible to detect when row data is collapsed or expanded

Tags: reactjs, ag-grid

I have requirement where i need do to some stuff when row data is collapsed in ag-grid. But i am not able to find specific function that helps when row data is collapsed in ag-grid

Comment: Elaborate more, i did not understand the context of row data collapse, are you talking about grouped data?

Comment: @SameerRezaKhan yes i am talking about grouped data in grid. when we collapse it is there any function to trigger at point of time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In ag -grid doc [Docs](https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-events/#miscellaneous) i find grid event `rowGroupOpened`

And screenshot of event in docs [Event](https://snag.gy/lTo47B.jpg)

You can bind to this event and use function what you want;

```
<ag-grid (rowGroupOpened)='yourFunction($event)'></ag-grid>
```

And in your controller

```
yourFunction(event){
  console.log("Hello world");
  console.log(event); // to look all event prop
}
```

This more complex for Angular, but i try to bring you idea.